# How do I stop my PHP error-log file from growing infinitely?

Tags: php, configuration, error-log

My PHP error log grew to occupy my entire disk in Ubuntu. Looking at the content I can see a loop of the following three lines:

```
[php7:warn] [pid 19943] [client 41.101.6.110:52722] PHP Warning:  feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/amine/app/pdf-download.php on line 33...
[php7:warn] [pid 19943] [client 41.101.6.110:52722] PHP Warning:  filesize(): stat failed for /home/amine/app/file.pdf in /home/amine/app/pdf-download.php on line 34...
[php7:warn] [pid 19943] [client 41.101.6.110:52722] PHP Warning:  fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/amine/app/pdf-download.php on line 34...
```

that continues forever.

The reason for this is that the user of the website clicks on a button that compiles some latex document to pdf and download the pdf. The latex compilation failed, and as a result the php script seems to be trying to get the file forever.

I have fixed the bug I had, but I am concerned that another bug would make the server unresponsive.

How would I stop this kind of issue?

Thanks.

Comment: post your code so we can look for you.

Answer (score 0):

Logs are important. And Ubuntu, like most Linux distributions, indeed most modern operating systems comes with tools for managing logs. Specifically you should be looking at logrotate (type "man 5 logrotate.conf" in a terminal session). The specifics of implementation depend on whether you are using mod_php in Apache or php-fpm.

I was fairly sure that Ubuntu came with a log rotation script for php-fpm (and it definitely has one for Apache + mod_php) so something is broken on your computer if its not auto-archiving your logs.